# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: django

Every time i try to access the admin page i get this error
and this is the Traceback

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs']
 Installed Middleware:
 ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/ajmi/spam/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html           (File exists)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/django/contrib/admindocs/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader:
```

The login.html File does not exist, how to fix this.
Thank you

Comment: I note that the traceback says that the file *does* exist in the app_directories loader. Is it maybe not readable or something similar? This is definitely an odd problem.

Comment: Yes, as @LukeSneeringer points out, look at your file system permissions. That means, see if you can actually open and read 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html with the same user permissions that you're running your test server with.

Comment: Thank you guys, i changed the permission to root user by typing: sudo python manage.py runserver. and it works very well

Comment: See my answer here if still not fixed for some of yours.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32358905/303681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, i changed the permission to root user by typing:

```
sudo python manage.py runserver.
```

and it works very well