# Admin Site: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm following Django's official [Tutorial 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/) but for some reason cannot create an admin site despite following all the steps correctly to my understanding.

This is the error I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/
admin/login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
admin/login.html
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 138
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/jcugley/Documents/Programming/Python/Django/mysite',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 24 Jan 2012 18:40:03 -0600
```

The error occurs after I uncomment the following lines (commented):

```
### urls.py ###
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin # THIS LINE
admin.autodiscover() # THIS LINE

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), # THIS LINE
)
```

If I comment them again it gets rid of the error.

I **do** have `django.contrib.admin` in my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Comment: What did you set TEMPLATE_DIRS and TEMPLATE_LOADERS on settings.py

Comment: TEMPLATE_DIRS is empty (nothing about it was mentioned in the tutorial) and TEMPLATE_LOADERS has 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader' and 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader' (Template loaders is also never mentioned)

Comment: Can you paste the whole code zip at dropbox or something?

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://cl.ly/2w0T2V3p2T3a1e1W3b20

Comment: Can you see and open template file on: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html ?

Comment: Code works perfectly for me. Ran it as-is except for changing the path to sqlite3.db (you should really just use a relative path for that), and admin loaded up fine with no errors.

Comment: @Jarrod Code works just fine here.

Comment: @MuratCorlu I have no /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates folder.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Weird that it is working for you guys :/ Also Chris I originally had a relative folder for the database dir, but it didn't work, so I had to change it to a static path.

Comment: @Jarrod looks like you need to reinstall django.

Comment: @Jarrod: The only appreciable difference I can spot is that I rolled a quick virtualenv with just Django 1.3.1 installed. Using virtualenv is a good idea regardless, so I'd try that if I were you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it works on other people's machines, and since you have the app directories loader enabled, admin site enabled in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and that's all it should take for templates to be discovered (I mean, what more can one do?) - I can only assume something is wrong with your django installation.

This would be a good chance to start using virtualenvs and a fresh install of django to rule out your settings:

Fire up a terminal, navigate to your project directory (doesn't actually matter...)

```
pip install virtualenv # if you don't have it.

virtualenv --no-site-packages env 
# this creates a virtual python environment that doesn't include system packages

source env/bin/activate
# this forces your bash session to use that environment

pip install django
# installs a fresh copy of django to your new environment

cd path_to_my_django_project    
# now go to your site directory

python manager.py runserver
# visit admin site.
```

Answer (score 31):

I ran into the same problem, and I had to force pip to re-download django.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed --force-reinstall --upgrade --no-cache-dir
```

Note: I know that the `--no-cache-dir` option is necessary, I'm not certain that the other options are all required.

Comment: This fixed it for me (using virtualenv). I think either virtualenv, pip or the user (probably) gets confused and django doesn't install properly when using virtualenv.

Comment: Might relate to installing through ssl, or multiple virtual environments?  I got errors `SNIMissingWarning` and `InsecurePlatformWarning` when using this, but created a fresh virtual environment and it worked, then executed the same command on the previous virtualenv and it worked(?) but threw those same errors.

Answer (score 11):

I am using Django Version 1.9.7 and when trying to add the admin_tools (menu and dashboard) to my application I had a similar issue.  I found I had to do three things:

1. Edit the INSTALLED_APPS option in settings.py as follows (**note that the admin_tools come before django contrib, 'mines' is the name of my application**):

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'admin_tools',
       'admin_tools.theming',
       'admin_tools.menu',
       'admin_tools.dashboard',
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'mines'
   ]
   ```
2. Edit the TEMPLATE setting in the settings.py file as follows (**note the 'loaders' option that got added, and that APP_DIRS are now set to false**):

   ```
   TEMPLATES = [{
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
       'DIRS': [],
       'APP_DIRS': False,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
               'django.template.context_processors.request',
               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
           ],
           'loaders': [
               'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
               'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
               'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
           ],
       },
   }]
   ```
3. And then finally I updated my urls.py file as follows (**note the include for the admin_tools urls**):

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import include,url
   from django.contrib import admin
   from mines.views import SummaryByMapIcon

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
       url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
       url(r'^summarybymapicon$', SummaryByMapIcon, name='summarybymapicon'),
   ]
   ```

Comment: If you are switching among Python/Django versions, the OP's problem can happen and Abrie's answer nicely summarizes what I needed to get an older branch (which had not been migrated to Python3 and Django 1.10) to work with my virtualenv that I have been using with my latest development branch.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this same problem by reinstalling Django with the `--no-cache-dir` option:

```
pip uninstall django
pip install django --no-cache-dir
```

Solved thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751001/why-does-my-aging-django-1-3-1-site-say-templatedoesnotexist-at-admin-after).

Comment: I suggest also adding `--no-binary Django` to this so it still works with current versions of pip.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had to change `APP_DIRS` from `False` to `True`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Strangely I found that sometime the `template` and `media` is not copied from your django/contrib/admin. Therefore you need to copy them to your virtual env django directory.

i.e from your `/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib` directory you need to

`ln -s ~/Sites/your_dj_app/venv/django/contrib/admin/templates templates`

and

`ln -s ~/Sites/your_dj_app/venv/django/contrib/admin/media media`

Comment: [Reinstalling Django with --no-binary option solves this problem without having to recreate symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747016/3748764).

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting a Django-application from an experienced magician, I wanted to understand the model by looking at it through Django-admin. As the app's model was not in Admin yet, I created an `admin.py` and ran into various problems. I tried All-Of-The-Above(TM) and found this:

1. **I got the paths confused.** I put the `admin.py` file into the wrong directory. If you have something like `.../app/app/app/app/app...` make sure you know which `app` needs to hold the `admin.py`. I figured that out by putting crap into the file and notice, that it would not crash. Hence 'crap' was not executed and something was wrong with the file. Fixed.
2. **`TemplateDoesNotExist` on 'admin/index.html'** The app's `settings.py` was configured to only run `django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2` as TEMPLATES BACKEND. But Admin needs the standard `django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates` to make it work. I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890665/after-installing-jinja2-templatedoesnotexist-at-admin), that it was possible to have two template-engines configured. I copied the standard-block from a different app. Fixed.
3. **`TemplateDoesNotExist` on 'admin/widgets/related_widget_wrapper.html'** While Admin was now working, looking at individual objects was still broken. I searched for the missing template and found it well in place. Changing anything on my `TEMPLATES` setting would not improve anything. I manually inserted paths in `'DIRS': []`, changed options, deleted the Jinja backend, nothing. It felt like was changing the wrong file again. Using the debugger, I found that even without configuring Jinja, it would still run Jinja. Finally, in `settings.py`, I spotted this:

   ```
   FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.Jinja2'
   ```

   and commenting it out got Admin going.

Not sure tho what it does with the rest of the application but for learning it's okay.

Comment: ATTENTION: For item 2, note that the ORDER of the 2 entries might be important. In my case, if I put the DjangoTemplates first, the admin works but the Jinja pages don't; if I do the opposite, then both work.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may happen if you changed something in `TEMPLATES` in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
           'django.template.context_processors.debug',
           'django.template.context_processors.request',
           'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
           'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

I have stumbled with this issue, alhamdulillah, my mistake was solved when I changed the `'APP_DIRS': False,` to `'APP_DIRS': True,`

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same error, after several times pip install and uninstall Django, it's still not work. Then I download Django tar.gz file from Django website, and install from this file , all is fine. Hopefully this can help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem trying to configure `django-admin-tools` for `Django 2.0.2`

Eventually I got it working. Here's my `TEMPLATES` settings.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders' : [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
                ]
        },
    },
]
```

This worked even as I overrode the default admin template.

Just be sure to take note of where to place the `django-admin-tools` apps. See @Abrie Nel's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

```
for windows user the admin_tools in the templates section should be place in the begining

   'loaders': [
            **'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',**    
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite their usefulness, the aforementioned answers are partial. I opine that the developer should know what is going on at the back-end, viz., "how" is this exception being raised.

As one can see in the exception that the Exception is TemplateDoesNotExist and the value name is the path, and something going wrong with the "loader.py" file. Although I was using Django 1.1.4, I am pretty sure the exception is being raised because of the line (in loader.py) where os.path.isdir(template_dir) is being checked. It cannot find the template folder(directory) in the django folder, which is located in the site-packages folder in the python's Lib folder.

Intuitively one can say it is because of the inappropriate installation of django. It is, however, a good exercise to find out the cause of the exception by rummaging through the source. When this error occured in my project, I did not reinstall django, instead I copied the folders from root (C:/Python27/django/contrib) -- yes I am using Windows -- to its counterpart in site-packages and it worked!

Comment: Please look at this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your quality up

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an "answer" as I cannot with my current "reputation" add a comment.

Following **Aaron** solution:

In a project with Django 1.4 with docker with the same issue (accessing yourproject/admin/login.html or yourproject/admin/index.html). I used in python.dockerfile this, and solved:

```
"RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir"
```

Before I did this, I verified entering inside the docker, that inside the folder usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/ didnt exist the folder /templates/.

I was reading this before coming to this post:
[https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=django-users@googlegroups.com&q=subject:%22TemplateDoesNotExist+at+%5C%2Fadmin%5C%2F%22&o=newest&f=1](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=django-users@googlegroups.com&q=subject:%22TemplateDoesNotExist%20at%20%5C%2Fadmin%5C%2F%22&o=newest&f=1)

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I have INSTALLED_APPS good, but just need to point inside TEMPLATE_DIRS the django admin template:

```
import os #Put at the starting line

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    ... #Another folder,
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'relative/path/to/virtualenv/my_env/django/contrib/admin/templates'),
)
```

And it works

Answer (score -1):

I think there are some packages that you didn't install in INSTALLED_APPS, in my case I installed 'import_export' since I used 'importexportmodels

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you include **'import_export'** in your **'INSTALLED_APPS'** in settings.py. As explained from [documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), django-import-export is a Django application and library for importing and exporting data with included admin integration. Therefore for template of application to be render on the browser, the name of application must be included in settings.py. Unless other, you will get an error 'Template does not exist'. Common sense, it is not possible to render the template of application, while the name of application is not not included in settings.py. So import_export is an application built in by Django, include it in settings.py.

Comment: The ask of the question is entirely different!