# After installing jinja2 TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/

Tags: python, django, jinja2, django-settings

I have installed jinja2 and after that 'DIRS' stopped working(I have to include them by hand).
Changing 'APP_DIRS' doesn`t help

templates look like that:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'APP_DIRS': False,
    'DIRS': ['main/templates', 'shop/templates'],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'environment': 'django_test.create_jinjia_env.environment',
        'autoescape': True,
        'auto_reload': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

If don`t include templates into DIRS it throws the same error

Didn`t find the questions like that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The Django admin app does not come with Jinja templates. If you wish to use Jinja and the admin app, you need to include both engines in your `TEMPLATES` setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,  # This allows Django to find the templates in the admin app
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        # The rest of your Jinja2 settings.
    },
```

Secondly, when `APP_DIRS` is True, the Jinja2 backend [looks for templates in a `jinja2` subdirectory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2). That means you should put your templates in `main/jinja2` and `shop/jinja2` instead of `main/templates` and `shop/templates`.

Comment: Thanks very helpful and laconic!

Comment: Also, if you inherit an existing application with Jinja and have problems turning on Admin after the fact, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49980601/1025430

Comment: ATTENTION: Note that the ORDER of the 2 entries might be important. In my case, if I put the DjangoTemplates first, the admin works but the Jinja pages don't; if I do the opposite, then both work.